# How do I run 2 functions in Pyglet?

Tags: python, windows, pyglet

I'm trying to create a Rock, Paper, Scissors game in Python using Pyglet. While running the 'on_draw' function I want it to allow the user to input "A" for rock, "P" for paper and "S" for scissors, but i can not find a solution. One idea i had, was that when you started up the 'window' it would set a background containing the text, but couldn't find any information on that either. If you have any ideas and have  a bit of spare time, I would greatly appreciate your help.

I've been trying to figure this out for a while, but i am quite new to Pyglet.

Here is my code so far...

```
import pyglet
from pyglet.window import key
import random
import time

window = pyglet.window.Window(width = 1000, height = 700, resizable = False, caption = "Rock, Paper, Scissors!")

#images saved in root of the .py file
bg = pyglet.image.load('bg.png')
sprite_bg = pyglet.sprite.Sprite(img=bg)

# all images are defined correctly and sprites(tested it and all works)

#default choice of the computer player and user
num1 = 0
num2 = 0 #num2 is the user

@window.event
#Here is where I want it to say "Rock - A, Paper - S, Scissors - D"
def on_key_press(symbol, modifiers):
    global num2
    if symbol == key.A:
        print ("Player: Rock")
        num2 = 0
        on_draw2()
    elif symbol == key.S:
        print ("Player: Paper")
        num2 = 1
        on_draw2()
    elif symbol == key.D:
        print ("Player: Scissors")
        num2 = 2
        on_draw2()


def on_draw():

    window.clear()
    sprite_bg.draw()

    num1 = random.randint(0, 2)
    if num1 == 0:
        sprite_r_right.draw()
    elif num1 == 1:
        sprite_p_right.draw()
    elif num1 == 2:
        sprite_s_right.draw()

    if num2 == 0:
        sprite_r_left.draw()
    elif num2 == 1:
        sprite_p_left.draw()
    elif num2 == 2:
        sprite_s_left.draw()

    if num1 == num2:
        both_win.draw()

    elif num2 == 0:
        if num1 == 1:
            right_win.draw()
        else:
            left_win.draw()

    elif num2 == 1:
        if num1 == 2:
            right_win.draw()
        else:
            left_win.draw()

    elif num2 == 2:
        if num1 == 0:
            right_win.draw()
        else:
            left_win.draw()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    pyglet.app.run()
```

I want the program to run like this:
1. Rock - A, Paper - S, Scissors - D and waits for an input of a, s or d
2. then sets 'num2' (the user) with 0, 1 or 2 (0 - rock, 1 - paper, 2 - 
   scissors)
3. random 'num1' (the computer player) with 0, 1 or 2
4. shows image of rock, paper or scissors on both sides and says who won
5. show score (not yet implemented)
6. repeat (not yet implemented)

Program runs like this:
1. blank screen (waiting for input of a, s or d)
2. does step 2, 3, 4 listed above

Comment: How familiar are you with classes and inheritance?

Comment: Not very familiar, but i'll do some research. Thanks

Comment: I've got a standard template i usually toss on people that will solve problems like these, and help with future structures of the code. But it requires that you're familiar with classes and inheritance. I'll try to make the code you got working so you don't get confused by a completely new set of code.

Answer (score 1):

There's a couple of problems with your code that we need to sort out.
The first being that `on_draw` won't get called unless the user presses a button, ideally.. This function gets called at certain intervals/interrupts within the framework.

We do this by doing:

```
@window.event # <-- This is key, if you forget this - the screen won't update
def on_draw():
    window.clear()
    sprite_bg.draw()
```

Later, your code uses a bunch of variables that doesn't exist, for instance, `sprite_r_right` is never defined. I'm guessing this is a sprite representing a rock or something similar. That's all fine, but for time purposes, I'm replacing this with a Label in my code below.

Another problem is that you do `num1 = random.randint(0, 2)` on every render-loop. Without checking if the user has supplied a choice or not. Ideally, you would do something like:

```
if num2 != 0:
    num1 = random.randint(0, 2)
```

*(Another quick note, these variable names are confusing as f*** and it's hard for anyone to really keep track of what they're used for. So in the code below, I've changed them to represent something that's more logical in terms of what they do or are used for)*

Here's a proposed example of how you could set up the logic:

```
import pyglet
from pyglet.window import key
import random
import time

window = pyglet.window.Window(width = 1000, height = 700, resizable = False, caption = "Rock, Paper, Scissors!")

#images saved in root of the .py file
bg = pyglet.image.load('bg.png')
sprite_bg = pyglet.sprite.Sprite(img=bg)

sprite_player = pyglet.text.Label("", x=(window.width/3), y=window.height/2)
sprite_computer = pyglet.text.Label("", x=window.width-(window.width/3), y=window.height/2)
sprite_result = pyglet.text.Label("", x=window.width/2, y=window.height/3, anchor_x="center")

@window.event
def on_key_press(symbol, modifiers):
    if symbol == key.A:
        sprite_player.text = 'Rock'

    elif symbol == key.S:
        sprite_player.text = 'Paper'

    elif symbol == key.D:
        sprite_player.text = 'Scissors'

    # Once the user presses a key, randomize the computers choice
    rng = random.randint(0, 2)
    if rng == 0:
        sprite_computer.text = 'Rock'
    elif rng == 1:
        sprite_computer.text = 'Paper'
    elif rng == 2:
        sprite_computer.text = 'Scissors'

@window.event # <-- This is key, if you forget this - the screen won't update
def on_draw():
    window.clear()
    sprite_bg.draw()

    if sprite_player.text != "" and sprite_computer.text != "":
        if sprite_player.text == sprite_computer.text:
            sprite_result.text = "Draw!"

        elif sprite_computer.text == "Rock":
            if sprite_player.text == "Paper":
                sprite_result.text = "Player wins"
            else:
                sprite_result.text = "Computer wins"

        elif sprite_computer.text == "Paper":
            if sprite_player.text == "Scissors":
                sprite_result.text = "Player wins"
            else:
                sprite_result.text = "Computer wins"

        elif sprite_computer.text == "Scissors":
            if sprite_player.text == "Rock":
                sprite_result.text = "Player wins"
            else:
                sprite_result.text = "Computer wins"
    else:
        sprite_result.text = "Press A for Rock, S for Paper and D for Scissors"

    sprite_player.draw()
    sprite_computer.draw()
    sprite_result.draw()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    pyglet.app.run()
```

This will show a quick "help" message, and as soon as the game has started, the results and choices will be shown.

A neater way tho, would be to use object oriented programming to solve a lot of the issues of rendering, keeping. Due to time, I'll have to come back and edit this answer with that solution, gotta go do some work heh.